# Flutter / Dart not returning a value from a locally hosted flask api

Tags: python, ios, api, flask, flutter

Using IOS, Visual Studio Code, Flask, VirtualEnv....

I've just started playing with Flask and Flutter.  I've created a locally hosted flask server which returns users via the api and I'm trying to access the api with Flutter with my usb attached IOS device.  When I try an api hosted on the internet, I get output on my phone, however when I point to the local API it does not look like it's hitting the server, I get no response in the flask server log stating a request was made.  What am I doing wrong?

Via my browser I can navigate to 127.0.0.1:5000/users and get the following output.  I expect this to appear on my phone:

> [{"name": "Nick", "age": 42, "occupation": "Network Engineer"},
>   {"name": "Elvin", "age": 32, "occupation": "Business Analyst"},
>   {"name": "Nick", "age": 22, "occupation": "Test Analyst"}]

Here is my flask server code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from flask import jsonify
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

users = [
    {
        "name": "Nick",
        "age": 42,
        "occupation": "Network Engineer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Elvin",
        "age": 32,
        "occupation": "Business Analyst"
    },
    {
        "name": "Nick",
        "age": 22,
        "occupation": "Test Analyst"
    }
]

class User(Resource):
    def get(self, name):
        for user in users:
            if(name ==user["name"]):
                return user, 200
        return "User not found@, 404"

    def post(self, name):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument("age")
        parser.add_argument("occupation")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        for user in users:
            if(name == user["name"]):
                return "User with name {} already exist".format(name), 400

        user = {
            "name": name,
            "age": args["age"],
            "occupation": args["occupation"]
        }
        users.append(user)
        return user, 201

    def put(self, name):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument("age")
        parser.add_argument("occupation")
        args = parser.parse_args()

        for user in users:
            if(name == user["name"]):
                user["age"] = args["age"]
                user["occupation"] = args["occupation"]
                return user, 200

        user = {
            "name": name,
            "age": args["age"],
            "occupation": args["occupation"]        
        }
        users.append(user)
        return user, 201

    def delete(self, name):
        global users
        users = [user for user in users if user["name"] != name]
        return "{} is deleted.".format(name), 200

@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def getUsers():
    return json.dumps(users)


api.add_resource(User, "/user/<string:name>")
app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: apitest2
description: A new Flutter project.

 version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+2

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:


  uses-material-design: true
```

Here is my API.dart - changing from 127... to my local IP address doesn't make a difference

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
//const baseUrl = "http://192.168.86.24:5000";
//const baseUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

class API {
  static Future getUsers() {
    var url = baseUrl + "/users";
    return http.get(url);
  }
}
```

Here is my User.dart

```
class User {
  String name;
  int age;
  String occupation;

  User(String name, int age, String occupation) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.occupation = occupation;
  }

  User.fromJson(Map json)
      : name = json['name'],
        age = json['age'],
        occupation = json['occupation'];

  Map toJson() {
    return {'name': name, 'age': age, 'occupation': occupation};
  }
}
```

Here is my Main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:apitest2/API.dart';
import 'package:apitest2/User.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      title: 'My Http App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyListScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyListScreenState();
}

class _MyListScreenState extends State {
  var users = new List<User>();

  _getUsers() {
    API.getUsers().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        users = list.map((model) => User.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUsers();
  }

  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("User List"),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text(users[index].name));
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Main Idea**

- If we want to make HTTP requests to our API from other computers or devices connected to our LAN, we should use the development computer IP address, 0.0.0.0 (for IPv4 configurations) or :: (for IPv6 configurations) as the desired IP address for our development server.
- If we specify 0.0.0.0 as the desired IP address for IPv4 configurations, the development server will listen on every interface on port 5000.

**Refer following solution, which also address a similar problem:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62371660/10031056